# Internet relay postfix with virtual alias and .forward

Tags: postfix, forwarding, smarthost, aliases

In a relay postfix for a domain, I am trying to configure so that each user indicates the e-mail destination address he wants in the .forward but as virtual_alias_maps is configured, it always takes the address indicated in /etc/postfix/virtual and skips the .forward configuration of each user. I can't find a configuration to solve this problem. Thank you very much in advance.